Acronis Incompatible with Kernel 6.8 on Ubuntu 24.04: How to Resolve?
I'm facing an issue with a production server running Ubuntu 24.04.
We use Acronis, but it only works with kernel 5.10 and earlier, while Ubuntu currently uses 6.8, which is not compatible with the installation of the CloudBackup.bin agent. This is significantly affecting our operations. Is it possible to somehow install the agent in a way that it uses kernel 5.10 while the rest of the applications on the server run on 6.8?
I tried using UML, but I couldn't get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions to help resolve this issue?

Please don't just add "random" tags. Ubuntu is not debian, the debian tag explicitly asks you to not use it with derivatives, and your question has nothing to do with debian CDs, either.


Is it possible to somehow install the agent in a way that it uses kernel 5.10 while the rest of the applications on the server run on 6.8?

No. You will need to tell the party you pay to update their agent. Linux 6 has been around for quite a while.
Downgrading the kernel would constitute a security downgrade, too.

I understand. Would it be possible for the software to somehow pull the information from the 5.10 kernel while isolating the rest of the machine?

There is no 5.10 kernel that could do that job in a meaningful manner, so: no, as said. This is 100% a problem that Acronis needs to solve. Again, a company that your company is paying to make your systems more reliable, not less by requiring hacks or kernel downgrades.

Thank you for all the support, and on second thought, it really doesn't make sense for a security company to require an old kernel to function. Thank you.
